# Решить методом встречи посередине!

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

> Найти количество подмножеств чья сумма меньше или равна указанного числа К;
>   Ограничения: максимальное число элементов множества n = 40,
>   каждое не должно превышать 10^16
>   и самое главное: время выполнения работы до 0.5 секунд и использование не больше 20МБ ОЗУ
>
> **Пример**:
>       ***Ввод:***
>   
>     n = 5, s = 1000,
>   
>     a[n] = { 100, 500, 500, 1500, 1000 }
>   
> ***Вывод:***
>   
> v = 7 + 1 (пустое подмножество) = { {пустое}, {100}, {500}, {100+500}, {500}, {100+500}, {1000}, {500+500} }

Пытался решить простым перебором сумм всех возможных подмножеств, но при н > 20 время выполнения работы экспоненциально растет.

Если кто может объяснить как работает это метод буду крайне благодарен.

Нашел такое вот объяснение:

> 1. Split the set of integers into 2 subsets say A and B. A having first n/2 integers and B having rest.
> 2. Find all possible subset sums of integers in set A and store in an array X. Similarly calculate all possible subset sums of integers in set B and store in array Y. Hence, Size of each of the array X and Y will be at most 2^(n/2).
> 3. Now merge these 2 subproblems. Find combinations from array X and Y such that their sum is less than or equal to S.
>
>    - One way to do that is simply iterate over all elements of array Y for each element of array X to check the existence of such a combination. This will take O( (2n/2)2) which is equivalent to O(2n).
>    - To make it less complex, first sort array Y and then iterate over each element of X and for each element x in X use binary search to find maximum element y in Y such that x + y <= S.
>    - Binary search here helps in reducing complexity from 2nto 2n/2log(2n/2)which is equivalent to 2n/2n.
>    - Thus our final running time is O(2n/2n).

Не очень понял третий пункт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это классическая задача на иллюстрацию принципа "встречи посередине", который кстати часто используется в криптографии.

Этот метод применяется (обычно) когда нужно решать NP - полную задачу. Метод сокращает с `O(2^N)` до `O(2^N/2)` что обычно в разы лучше.

Если нам нужно вычислить число наборов, таких что `F[a1,a2,...,an] = X` и мы имеем возможность эффективно вычислить обратную `F^-1` (т.е в идеале операция обратима и редуцируется до некого просто цикла с одним аккумулятором). Например для сложения это тоже сложение (окей вычитание), для умножения - деление (в кольце обычно), для побитового или оно само и тому подобное. То можно сделать следующую операцию.

1. составить обратную функцию
2. разделить набор элементов на 2 части, таким образом, чтобы число вариантов в каждой части (без пересечения) было примерно одинаковым. В простейшем случае - просто на 2 равные части.
3. составить таблицу `F^-1[X, al, al+1, ... , an]` (всю таблицу). Поясню. Смысл этой операции - мы должны получить значение аккумулятора, такое что после добавления этой части массива мы получим в результате число `X`
4. перебрать наборы `{a1,a2,...,al-1}` Для каждого набора вычисляем `F[a1,a2,...,al-1]=Y` После чего берём из таблицы пункта 3 набор для которого `F^-1 = Y`

В данном случае случай канонический.

1. Составляем таблицу всем сумм для элементов `1,2...N/2`
2. Перебираем все суммы оставшегося списка `N/2+1, ... , N` Для каждой суммы нужно добавить к ответу число сумм из пункта 1 меньше `k - Summ`.  (для этого лучше использовать бинарный поиск).

Кстати может быть полезно [Всевозможные произведения в массиве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616454/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5/616468#616468)

Код пока не пишу. Возникнут вопросы - добавлю.

Comment: можете добавить, я хочу узнать можно ли ещё оптимизировать код (есть решённый вариант)

Comment: @Melliodas скиньте лучше ваш вариант, я думаю так будет проще, чем потом сравнивать 2 варианта)