# Оптимизация решения задачи

Tags: python, оптимизация, рекурсия, олимпиада, перебор

Есть Задача

Даны N целых чисел X1, X2, ..., XN. Расставить между ними знаки "+" и "-" так, чтобы значение получившегося выражения было равно заданному целому S.

Входные данные
В первой строке находятся числа N и S. В следующей строке - N чисел через пробел. 2 <= N <= 24, 0 <= Xi <= 50 000 000, -1 000 000 000 <= S <= 1 000 000 000.

Выходные данные
Если получить требуемый результат невозможно, вывести "No solution", если можно, то вывести равенство. Если решение не единственное, вывести любое.

Примеры
входные данные
3 13
7 3 9
выходные данные
7-3+9=13
входные данные
3 1
7 3 9
выходные данные
7+3-9=1
входные данные
3 3
7 10 0
выходные данные
No solution

Решил на Python рекурсией. Все тесты проходит кроме двух, на которых не успевает уложиться во время.

```
n, s = list(map(int, input().split()))
x = list(map(int, input().split()))

cursum = sum(x)
def p(k, summ):
    if summ == s:
        return True
    if k == 0:
        return summ == s

    x[k] = -x[k]
    if p(k-1, summ+2*x[k]):
         return True
    x[k] = -x[k]
    if p(k-1, summ):
        return True
    return False


def concate_string(mas, res):
    if not res:
        return "No solution"
    string = str(mas[0])
    for elem in range(1, len(mas)):
        if mas[elem] >= 0:
            string += '+' + str(mas[elem])
        else:
            string += str(mas[elem])
    return string+'='+str(s)


res = p(n-1, cursum)
print(concate_string(x, res))
```

Стопится на данных

24 -80507031

8593682 31716735 21491280 17902794 33317802 31903797 43140236 27960611 49962940 89871 21765518 824859 10008534 49081942 37138133 10339902 46783173 45482021 19050964 36953244 15710201 13017280 32752188 4020978

Может ли кто нибудь помочь с оптимизацией? Или на питоне быстрее не получится?

Comment: странно, твое решение у меня отрабатывает за 3 секунды

Comment: почему рекурсия быстрее перебора в варианте "No solution"???

Comment: вообще классическая задача на MiM https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/897962/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5/898015#898015 такой подход может на порядок ускорить.

Comment: спасибо @pavel, Ваш комментарий очень помог

Answer (score 0):

Решается без рекурсий в один проход ещё медленней. А то что у нас только 2 знака упрощает задачу двоичной арифметикой.

```
N, S = list(map(int, input().split()))
Xs = list(map(int, input().split()))
v = 0

maskmasks = [ (i,2**i) for i in range(N-1)]

for mask in range(2**N):    
    v = Xs[0]
    print('\r{0:b}'.format(mask).replace('0','-').replace('1','+'), end='')            
    for i,m in maskmasks:
        if m & mask:
            v+=Xs[i+1]
        else:
            v-=Xs[i+1]
    print(' {}    ~{} %      '.format(mask,100*mask//2**N), end='')
    if v==S:
        print('\nДа ^^')        
        break
else:
    print('Нет')
```

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен конечно в скорости, но попробуй. Или если есть возможность укажи в вопросе сайт и номер задачи для тестов.

```
from itertools import product


n, s = list(map(int, input().split()))
x = list(map(int, input().split()))

result = ''
for signs in product([1, -1], repeat=n-1):
    if sum([x[0]] + [value * sign for (value, sign) in zip(x[1:], signs)]) == s:
        result = '+'.join(map(str, [x[0]] + [value * sign for (value, sign) in zip(x[1:], signs)])).replace('+-', '-') + '=' + str(s)
        break
if (result):
    print(result)
else:
    print('No solution')
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу
Изначально я ее нашел на сайте informatics.mcccme.ru
Там ее взяли из учебника по олимпиадному программированию Меньшикова, только вот в чем заключалась загвоздка, в учебнике был предложен способ решения, который я привел в вопросе, и ограничение по времени - 3 секунды. На сайте же, ограничение было 1 секунда, из-за этого решение с рекурсией не проходило.
В новом решении мне помог комментарий про метод MiM - Meet in the middle. Вкратце этот метод помогает снизить сложность экспоненциального алгоритма почти в 2 раза. Идея заключается в том, что мы представляем задачу в виде уравнения.
Допустим нам дан массив из чисел 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, а получить нам нужно число 9
представим это в виде a+b+c+d+e+f=9, и заметим, что a+b+c=-(d+e+f)+9
Таким образом можно искать для каждой половинки исходного массива все возможные суммы, со всеми возможными знаками. Поначалу можно показаться, что нет разницы, найти все комбинации целого множества, или двух его половинок, но нет, булеан множества из 24 элементов равен 2^24, булеан половины множества - 2^12, две половины 2^12+2^12 = 2^13 что снижает количество действий на 11 порядков!!!
Окей, переходим к реализации. Она написана костыльно, потому что решил ее только что, позже сделаю апдейт, приведу код к более менее нормальному виду

```
n, s = list(map(int, input().split()))
x = list(map(int, input().split()))

left = x[0:n//2]
right = x[n//2::]

cursum_left = sum(left)
cursum_right = sum(right)

sign_left = ['+' for _ in range(len(left))]
sign_right = ['+' for _ in range(len(right))]

summ_left = {cursum_left: sign_left[::]}
summ_right = {cursum_right: sign_right[::]}


def first_half(k, summ):
    if k == 0:
        return
    sign_left[k] = '-'
    summ -= 2*left[k]
    summ_left[summ] = sign_left[::]
    first_half(k-1, summ)
    sign_left[k] = '+'
    summ += 2*left[k]
    summ_left[summ] = sign_left[::]
    first_half(k-1, summ)


def second_half(k, summ):
    if k == -1:
        return
    sign_right[k] = '-'
    summ -= 2*right[k]
    summ_right[summ] = sign_right[::]
    second_half(k-1, summ)
    sign_right[k] = '+'
    summ += 2*right[k]
    summ_right[summ] = sign_right[::]
    second_half(k-1, summ)


def find():
    for left_elem in summ_left:
        if -(left_elem-s) in summ_right:
            return summ_left[left_elem] + summ_right[-(left_elem-s)]


def concate_string(arr, signs):
    if not signs:
        return "No solution"
    result = f'{arr[0]}'
    for i in range(1, len(signs)):
        result += signs[i] + str(arr[i])

    return result+'='+str(s)

first_half(len(left)-1, cursum_left)
second_half(len(right)-1, cursum_right)
result_signs = find()
print(concate_string(x, result_signs))
```

А если это нахождение половин делегировать потокам, то думаю выйдет еще быстрее