# Как сделать перебор всех возможных комбинаций в массиве?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, алгоритм

Допустим, на вход даётся

> [1, 2, 5, 3]

Нужно получить все возможные комбинации их сумм

**На выходе**

> [3, 6, 4, 7, 5, 8, 8, 6, 9, 11]

Т.е:

1 + 2 = 3

1 + 5 = 6

1 + 3 = 4

2 + 5 = 7

2 + 3 = 5

5 + 3 = 8

...

(1+2) + 5 = 8

(1+2) + 3 = 6

(1+5) + 3 = 9

(1+2+5) + 3 = 11

**Вот мой код написанный на питоне**

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
firstEl = arr[i]
for j in range(len(arr) - 1):
    if arr[i] == arr[j+1]:
        pass
    else:
        arr.append(arr[i] + arr[j + 1])
```

Он работает не так, как нужно.

Он выводит(вывод я отсортировал и убрал повторяющиеся эл-ты):

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616454/%d0%92%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5)  вопрос о всех возможных произведениях. Понятно, что достаточно поменять умножение на сложение... :) Кстати, а почему у вас запрещена сумма 5+2? 3+2? 5+2+3?

Comment: Это алгоритм, который (если я не ошибаюсь) будет иметь эффективность `O(n!)`, откуда появляется вопрос... оно вам точно надо?

Comment: @raviga при выполнении условия я выйду из цикла. Поэтому в худшем случае у него будет такая эффективность.

Comment: @Harry это моя ошибка)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм со сложностью `O(N*MaxSum)`.
Работает на принципе: сумму `K` можно составить из элемента cо значением `item` и суммы `(K - item)`, если такая уже есть, набранная из других элементов. Цикл в обратном направлении позволяет избежать двойного использования элемента в сумме.

```
arr = [1, 3, 5, 8]
sm = sum(arr)
sums = set()
sums.add(0)

for item in arr:
    for k in range(sm, min(arr) - 1, -1):
        if (k - item) in sums:
            sums.add(k)
print(sums)

{0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17}
```

Если сумма всех элементов велика, а самих элементов не так много, то выгоднее может быть использовать алгоритм генерации всех подмножеств и подсчёт их сумм со сложностью `O(2^N)`

Comment: извините, вы бы не могли подсказать, как заставить этот алгоритм работать пока не выполнится условие. Допустим, алгоритм прошёл первый круг, нашёл комбинации, как пойти по второму, третьему и т.д кругу, пока не будет выполнено определенное условие?

Comment: Какое условие? Если определённая сумма S, то нужно просто range с этой суммы начинать.

Comment: @ MBo пользователь вводит число и мы должны перебирать все комбинации пока не найдем то число, которое делится на введённое число без остатка. Допустим [2,3,5] у меня останавливается на [2,3,5,7,8,10], а нужно, чтобы искалось ещё больше комбинаций, пока не поделится на 16(пример) без остатка. Должен получится [2,3,5,7,8,10,12,13,15,17,18,20...32]

Comment: В том месте, где `sums.add(k)` - проверять на делимость

Comment: if k % 16 != 0: break ?

Comment: нужно два цикла остановить, так что, если это сделано отдельной функцией - return,иначе break c выставлением флага для внешнего цикла

Comment: можно увидеть код? Питоном не особо хорошо владею)

Comment: В виде функции будете оформлять? Что она должна вернуть?

Comment: в виде функции, возвращается список комбинаций до того момента пока не будет делится на переменную, допустим, "a", без остатка

Comment: Ничего не пойму (смысл этого действия). В любом случае, это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: в любом случае, спасибо