# Посчитать кол-во способов представить число в виде произведения чисел фибоначи

Tags: python, c++, алгоритм, олимпиада

Сегодня был на олимпиаде по информатике, там была задача посчитать кол-во способов представить число в виде произведения чисел фибоначи.

Например:
Число: 8,
Ответ: 2,
Тк `2*2*2=8` и 8=8

Числа фибоначи для удобства:
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55

К сожалению, код не разрешили с собой забрать, а с телефона сейчас писать не хочу.

Итак, что я написал там:

Набрал 32 балла на пайтон, переписал на С++ - все равно 32 балла. Зря время потратил(

Я написал функцию, которая создает массив чисел Фибоначи до n

И функцию `check(num, layer=0)`
В ней определил базовый случай - если число num есть в массиве фибоначи, то увеличиваю count на 1.

А иначе я вызывал рекурсивно `check(num/fibNumber, layer+1)`

Но тогда 40 = 5 на 8 и 8 на 5 - 2 варианта, а это 1 вариант.

Тогда я создал глобальный массив layers, в который добавлял из базового случая переменную layer, которая увеличивается для каждого деления на 1. И тогда просто не увеличивал счетчик, если такое кол-во множителей уже было.

Алгоритм работвет, но не вкладывается по времени в ограничение 1.2 секунды. Ни на пайтоне, ни на cpp.

Как можно решить такую задачу эффективнее?

Ограничения:
1.2 сек
512мб памяти

Python 3.1 (не pypy)
Gnu c++ ... - точно не помню

Comment: ограничения напишите.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616454/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5/616468#616468

Вот тут лобовое решение, которое быстрее рекурсии вполне может быть.

Comment: Рекурсия должна быть по номеру числа Фибоначчи. Для первой сотни чисел будет мнговенно работать. Язык не важен.